# By first click select div and unselect others, by second click on the same div unselect it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to have the following scenario:

- only one div can be selected at the time (**DONE**)
- by click on the div it should be selected and other divs should stay unselected (**DONE**)
- **by click on the already selected div**, that div should be unselected and other divs will stay also unselected(***TO DO***)

I'm having problem to implement the last feature where by click on the already selected div to unselect it and other already working features should work as before. Could someone help me to make it work ?

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('optionsecoptions')
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var selectedEl = document.querySelector(".selected");
    if (selectedEl) {
      selectedEl.classList.remove("selected");
    }
    this.classList.add("selected");

  }, false);
}
```

```css
.optionsecoptions {
  width: 400px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #bbb8b8;
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.optionsecoptions:hover,
.optionsecoptions:active {
  background-color: #226fa3;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease-in, border-color 0.4s ease-in;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #226fa3;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease-in, border-color 0.4s ease-in;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top:10px;">
  <div class="optionsecoptions">
    Computers
  </div>
  <div class="optionsecoptions" style="top:151px;">
    Electronics
  </div>
  <div class="optionsecoptions" style="top:212px;">
    Mechanical
  </div>
  <div class="optionsecoptions" style="top:273px;">
    Electrical
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntxuc69a/9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
// If there was a selected element which is not this
if (selectedEl && selectedEl !== this) {
  selectedEl.classList.remove("selected");
}
// Toggle this
this.classList.toggle("selected");
```

As noted in the comments, your styles are a little misleading. You may want to have different styles on `:hover` and `.selected`. The demo below also changes that.

Demo:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('optionsecoptions')
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var selectedEl = document.querySelector(".selected");
    // If there was a selected element which is not this
    if (selectedEl && selectedEl !== this) {
      selectedEl.classList.remove("selected");
    }
    // Toggle this
    this.classList.toggle("selected");

  }, false);
}
```

```css
.optionsecoptions {
  width: 400px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #eceded;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in;
}

.optionsecoptions:hover { background-color: #bfe5ff; }
.optionsecoptions:active { background-color: #2d546f; color: #ffffff; }
.selected { background-color: #226fa3; color: #ffffff; }
.selected:hover { background-color: #4d99cc; }
```

```html
<div class="optionsecoptions">
  Computers
</div>
<div class="optionsecoptions" style="top:151px;">
  Electronics
</div>
<div class="optionsecoptions" style="top:212px;">
  Mechanical
</div>
<div class="optionsecoptions" style="top:273px;">
  Electrical
</div>
```

Comment: Not only do you not describe why this works, but it doesn't do what the OP says needs to be done.

Comment: @ScottMarcus ? I'm honestly curious as why you say that? I commented my code, and to my understanding, it does what the OP asked. What's different?

Comment: Click on an item (it will become selected). Click on that item again (it will remain selected). The OP wants an already selected item to become de-selected when you click on it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus it's not, you need to move your mouse away to see the result. That's just CSS on hover that makes it look selected :) LDropl, you might want to fix this UX issue, as it misled Scott

Comment: @ScottMarcus he did actually everything right, exactly what I needed. I didn't get also why you downvoted his answer

Comment: He was probably misled by the fact that your `:hover` styles are the same as `.selected` ones

Comment: Your satisfaction with the answer goes against good UX design. I shouldn't have to move my mouse off of the item to see that it is no longer selected. It should de-select as soon as I click it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus could you suggest any alternative answer ? It's a good point actually

Comment: The use of the CSS `hover` and `active` pseudo-classes should be removed and the effect should be done exclusively with JavaScript `.classList`.

Comment: The different color (for de-selected items) is better, but I would suggest a very light color for hover and a very dark color for selected. I might even change the color of the text upon hover and change the color of the background upon selection of the item. Remember that different people will have different visual acuity and may not distinguish colors the way you do.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I would like to ask also if there any chance to rewrite this code without using ```for-loop``` at all ?

Comment: If you're not using a library, you have to loop over all elements to add an event listener to them, or use event delegation: set up an event listener on a common ancestor - the more specific, the better, and inside, check whether the clicked element (target) has the `opsionsecoptions` class. Demo for that method: https://jsfiddle.net/4s9jh5f0/

Comment: But note that this will only work if your elements don't have other elements inside them. If they do, these inner elements might be the "target" instead of your elements, in which case you would need to check whether an ancestor of the target is `.optionsecoptions`, which will make it more complex... I would not recommend it if you're looking for clarity in your code

Comment: unfortunately I have more complex structure of my div elements. I have some weird bug by first click on the div nothing happens, only if I click once again than the div will be selected. The same for when I'm unselecting selected div: by first click nothing happens only by second click. Do you have idea what could it be ?

Comment: @LDropl What code are you using? The one from my answer, or the JSFiddle one? If it's the JSFiddle one, that's what I was talking about. The `event.target` might be an element inside the `.optionsecoptions`. In this case, nothing will happen, because this inner element does not have the class we're looking for. To fix this, you can look for the closest ancestor which has the class: https://jsfiddle.net/k13t2gxv/1/

Comment: Also, if you're using that version and your HTML structure is heavy, it might introduce some performance issues, because it will listen to every click and look for an ancestor which has the class. To reduce that risk, instead of `document.body`, use something which is more specific. For example, I don't know what your page looks like, but if all of your `.optionsecoptions` elements are inside a div with an ID "menu", you would do `document.getElementById('menu').addEventListener(...)`, that will be less overkill

Comment: @blex I was using the code with the ```for-loop```. I'm trying to use eventListener as you wrote

Comment: Oh ok, in that case it's hard to tell. If you're able to reproduce the issue in a JSFiddle, I can have a look

Comment: ok I will try to investigate more and will try another implementation. Thanks anyway